# Use Mirror(reflecting: ) on Core Data NSManagedObject

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsdictionary

I use the following code to add an object to Core Data. Why is it when I use `Mirror(reflecting: )` on the the object, nothing prints out?

Saving works fine.

```
var dict = [String: Any]()
dict.updateValue("abc", forKey: "uid")

guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {return}
let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
let entity: NSEntityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "MyModel", in: context)!

let object: NSManagedObject = NSManagedObject(entity: entity, insertInto: context)

for (k,v) in dict {
    object.setValue(v, forKey: k)
}

let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: object)
let properties = mirror.children
for property in properties {
    print("key: \(property.label as Any) = value: \(property.value)")
}

do {
    try context.save()
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("could not save . \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
}
```

Comment: Since you know that `object` is an `NSManagedObject`, it would be much better to use its `entity` property to find out the names of its properties.

Comment: @TomHarrington thanks. I'm just getting started with CoreData. I literally first started to use it yesterday.  I'm unfamiliar with what your recommending.

Comment: Every `NSManagedObject` has a property called `entity` that has information about its entity description. That property is an instance of `NSEntityDescription`. The entity description has several properties to tell you about the entity-- for example `propertiesByName`, `attributesByName`, etc. Basically Core Data has its own way to look up all of the properties and relationships that works better (for Core Data objects) than something like `Mirror` would.

Comment: @TomHarrington thanks for the explanation! I did a little digging around and care across a few posts that used `NSEntityDescription` but they weren’t very clear. I was definitely looking for a built in way to iterate through the object. I read Mirroring was slow? But anyway thank you for the your help. Have a safe and happy holiday season!